# Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode after firebase packages I added to my application... Flutter launching... mode

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode after firebase packages I added to my application... Flutter launching... mode and this process continues until the end without anything happening. If I remove the packages I added, the application works.

it works, before

[image]

after added the firebase_storage: ^11.5.6cloud_firestore: ^4.13.6 packages. It stays that way

[image]

What should I do ?

UPDATE! IT SOLVED: the issue was solved by time :) After the installation of firebase packages (especially cloud_firestore), the application opened after an abnormal first build process for about 10 minutes. If you experience a similar situation, if you do not see any errors in the terminal or debug console, just wait for the application to build. After the first build, each build will take a short time.

Comment: The issue was solved by time :)  After the installation of firebase packages (especially cloud_firestore), the application opened after an abnormal first build process for about 10 minutes. If you experience a similar situation, if you do not see any errors in the terminal or debug console, just wait for the application to build. After the first build, each build will take a short time.